# Can't see calls to function or constant value in optimized compiler-generated assembly

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, compiler-optimization

I am looking through assembly generated by my trivial C++ program. The full listing is:

```
test_func_0(int):
        add     edi, 15
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        divss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        cvttss2si       eax, xmm0
        ret
test_func_1(int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        add     eax, 15
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, eax
        divss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        cvttss2si       eax, xmm0
        ret
test_func_2(int*):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        add     eax, 15
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, eax
        divss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        cvttss2si       eax, xmm0
        ret
.LC1:
        .string " "
main:
        push    r12
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        push    rbp
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     r12, QWORD PTR [rbp+240+rax]
        test    r12, r12
        je      .L10
        cmp     BYTE PTR [r12+56], 0
        je      .L7
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [r12+67]
.L8:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        add     rsp, 8
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L7:
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r12]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    [QWORD PTR [rax+48]]
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L8
.L10:
        call    std::__throw_bad_cast()
_GLOBAL__sub_I_test_func_0(int):
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
.LC0:
        .long   1077936128
```

And it is geneaterd from

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int test_func_0 (int my_int)
{
     return (my_int + 15) / 3.0f;
}

int test_func_1 (int& my_int)
{
     return (my_int + 15) / 3.0f;
}

int test_func_2 (int* my_int)
{
     return (*my_int + 15) / 3.0f;
}


int main()
{
    int a = 17;
  
    std::cout << test_func_0(a) << " ";
    std::cout << test_func_1(a) << " ";
    std::cout << test_func_2(&a) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I believe I have been able to understand a lot of this, but three things I'm not seeing are:

1. Where are my functions being called? I see the long calls to std::cout (as well as a weird cout looking thing `OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout`), but no explicit calls to `test_func_1(int&)`.
2. Where has my `17` gone?? I can understand it being taken as const and inlined somewhere.. but where?
3. I thought my `17` might have been the `.long   1077936128` at the bottom, but in a weird format, but I'm not convinced by this. So what is this `1077936128` number?

C++ Insights helps a little by showing me:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 17;
  std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(test_func_0(a)), " ");
  std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(test_func_1(a)), " ");
  std::cout.operator<<(test_func_2(&a)).operator<<(std::endl);
  return 0;
}
```

Doing various inlines, as I thought. But I still don't see in the assembly where the functions are called.

Comment: Semi-related re: optimization effects and making asm that's still interesting to look at despite that: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)  e.g. `__attribute__((noinline,noclone))`, or just don't provide a definition, only prototype, for the callees.

Comment: Oh yes! Only a declaration would have been a smarter way of attempting to stop it from inlining! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your functions were all inlined, so there aren't any calls to them in `main`. Instead, their result is used directly.
2. The value 17 doesn't appear in your code because the compiler performed the calculations at compile time. All functions return `int((17+15)/3.0f)` which is 10. And you can see `mov esi, 10` three times in the generated assembly, which is used to pass the value to `basic:ostream::operator<<`.
3. 1077936128 is the representation of `3.0f` when read as an integer from memory. (See [Understanding GCC's floating point constants in assembly listing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883374/understanding-gccs-floating-point-constants-in-assembly-listing-output) for details).  It is only used in the three functions and not in `main` (where constant-propagation resulted in a simple integer at compile-time).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense, but why are those functions even written out if I compiled with -O3 and they are not used at all? Is it in case this is being used as a library by something else or something?

Comment: Yes, the compiler doesn't know if you will link this with another file which calls these functions. If you mark them as `static` then they probably won't appear in the assembly.

Comment: Yup, internal linkage through static got rid of them! Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: @Cascades: `-fwhole-program` would probably also enable that optimization without `static`, telling GCC that the source file(s) on the command line are the entire program.  Maybe also `-flto` (link-time whole-program / cross-file optimization.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oh, great to know! Thanks.